# Solana Validator extracting genesis.tar.bz2 does not produce genesis.bin

Tags: solana-program, rpc, ledger

Solana Newbie here.

I am trying to setup an RPC node for extracting data from the Solana chain. However I am having trouble launching the Solana Validator. I feel like I must be missing a dependency or something, but I'm struggling to find it.

When I launch the validator on mainnet-beta:

`solana-validator --identity ~/validator-keypair.json  --no-voting --rpc-port 8899`

I get get the following in the logs:

```
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632432080Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Done.
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632442774Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Cleaning accounts paths..
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632524114Z INFO  solana_core::validator] done. clean_accounts_paths took 69us
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632530408Z INFO  solana_core::validator] Geyser plugin: accounts_update_notifier: false transaction_notifier: false
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632534603Z INFO  solana_core::system_monitor_service] Starting SystemMonitorService
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632646258Z INFO  solana_core::validator] loading ledger from "/home/crash/ledger"...
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632670603Z INFO  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] Extracting "/home/crash/ledger/genesis.tar.bz2"...
[2022-10-28T17:49:00.632693839Z WARN  solana_runtime::hardened_unpack] Failed to open ledger genesis_config at "/home/crash/ledger": Unable to open "/home/crash/ledger/genesis.bin": Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }, IO error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

When I look at that directory all I have is:
admin.rpc, ledger.lock, and snapshot.

I've tried using version 1.14.6, stable channel, and prebuilt binaries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify an entrypoint in order to join a network, otherwise, the validator thinks it's starting a new network, and will look for a genesis file.

```
solana-validator \
  --identity ~/validator-keypair.json \
  --no-voting \
  --rpc-port 8899 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001
```

You may also need to specify some known validators from which to fetch a snapshot: https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#known-validators

You can find more information at https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#connect-your-validator